# What is the difference between Microsoft AJAX and AJAX Pro?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxpro

What is the difference between Microsoft AJAx and AJAX Pro?

Also, for what should I use AJAX Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft AJAX is Microsoft's Ajax library that contains ready to use server controls.

AJAX Pro is a free AJAX library, that enables you to implement your Ajax calls manually. It's a little bit difficult to use then Microsoft's controls. But you have more control on the data and html elements with this library.

With AJAX Pro, you define AjaxMethods, and call them in client-side. with callback methods you get the return value and implement your logic. Whole serializable .NET objects converted successfully to javascript objects.

In Ajax Pro when you make an ajax call, only the method you defined is called. In Microsoft Ajax, whole page life-cycle called instead. Because of this, you can not change properties of controls on page with Ajax Pro. You should do it manually by callback functions in javascript. But in Microsoft AJAX, you have ability to change control's properties in Ajax methods.

My suggestion, if you have knowledge of Javascript and HTML, try Ajax Pro or JQuery for AJAX. But if you're a newbie, begin with Microsoft Ajax.

Comment: I developed a solution based on AJAXPro and I found that whole page life-cycle is called? any suggestions to call defined method only?

Comment: Are you sure ? because in AJAX Pro you register a class (no need to inherit page class) as ajax method provider, and call it in your clientside code. so you can register a class that is not inherit page class, and call it in your clientside code. This will be exact solution.

Comment: Ummm. I indeed inherit from Page class. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

if you like the way AJAX pro works then i suggest you look at www.coolite.com, they are amazing controls, the people there took EXTJS and did all he pluming work for you and you have great fast controls, where you can also define Ajaxmethods, Webmehtods.

also if you really want to use Microsoft Ajax, then i advise using Teleirk Ajax Controls set, it is built upon Microsoft Ajax framework, but with enormous options and great support, i personally use them everyday.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the developer of Ajax Pro went on to work for Microsoft when they built Atlas.